# Reading text from file and converting it to UTF32

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, utf-32

I'm using CSFML 1.6 library (it's multimedia library based on OpenGL). And I live in Poland, here we have special characters like:

```
ąęźćół
```

Now I have a text file which consists this characters and CSFML offer function to set UnicodeText on displayed string, it's argument is array of ints.

How can I properly read characters from file and then pass them to this function?

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: That text file that you have, is it UTF-8, UTF-16, or something else? Also, are we talking about Windows + Visual Studio here?

Comment: We are talkign about Windws and Visual C++ 2008 EE, just tell me in which one should I save .txt file when using Notepad to do so.

Comment: there are not many options, why dont you try it out yourself?

Comment: I tried everything. I don't know how should I properly read UTF8 text and then transfer it to int array UTF32?x_x

Answer (score 0):

Judging to [sfml-dev](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.5/graphics-fonts.php), the library accepts either **char** string in **ISO-8859-1**, or **wchar_t** string in **UTF16**, or there's a possibility to provide a completely own charset.

I suppose, the simplest is to stick with UTF16. Save your text in UTF16, and use the "wstring family" functions (those beginning with 'w', like `wcscmp()`) to handle it.

Comment: That is great but function takes array of ints, how should I convert it?